# onAppear is causing problem with the preview but no error is shown

Tags: core-data, swiftui

self learning beginner here.

When I remove `.onAppear{add()}`, the preview works fine.  I tried to attach it to other the body view, the Vstack but it causes another error.  I read/watched several tutorials but nothing like this is mentioned....

Any help is appreciated

```
struct ListView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var targets: FetchedResults<TargetEntity>
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var positives: FetchedResults<PositiveEntity>

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text("+")
        .onAppear{add()} 
        .onTapGesture (count: 2){
            do {
                increment(targets.first!) //I also sense that doing "!" is not good.  But it's the only way I can keep it from causing error "Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults' to expected argument type 'X'"
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
    
func increment(_ item: TargetEntity) {
        item.countnum += 1
        save()
}

func add() {
    let countnum = TargetEntity(context: moc)
    countnum.countnum = 0
    save()
}

func save() {
    do { try moc.save() } catch { print(error) }
}
```

}

[image]

EDIT 20220509:
As advised by @Yrb (great thanks), the error is likely caused by the lack of a proper set up of preview var in the persistence file. I post the relevant code here for visiblity.

Data Controller file

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CounterLateApr")
    
    init () {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

preview code in a view

```
struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ListView()
        }        
    }
}
```

[AppName].app file

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct CounterLateAprApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your PreviewProvider. I suspect you forgot to add `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)`, assuming you are using the default Core Data manager.

Comment: Tip: Instead of having a fetch request for each entity you can use entity inheritance to fetch both entities in one fetch request.

Comment: Did you look at Diagnostics ?

Comment: @PtitXav Just looked at it.  MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for send render message to agent

==================================

|  MessageError: Connection interrupted

Comment: @Yrb Just posted the preview code.   IIRC, I didn't clicked Core Data when I created this project, but i could be wrong.  and the code I have in the [appname]app.swift file is this: 

@ StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }

Comment: @malhal Thanks! let me google how that works.

Comment: I just saw the preview code. It is what I thought. In light of your prior comments, do you have a file named `Persistence`? Or a file that contains an `NSPersistentContainer`?

Comment: @Yrb Sorry for getting back late.  I tried several ways to put your suggestion in the preview code but I couldn't make it work.  I have the a file name DataController and some code in the [appname].app file.  Thank you thank you

https://imgur.com/a/TVNNWtr

Comment: You need to edit your question and post the code itself, though at this level of learning Core Data you may want to stick with Apple's default implementation. The error that you are seeing is because you don't have a `preview` var set up in your data controller to provide a Core Data store for testing. I can get one working for you, but using the default `PersistenceController` that Apple provides when you select a new Core Data project will be easier for you to start with.

Comment: @Yrb Thank you so much!  I edited the post as advised.   I also tried to see what is the default code in Apple's default PersistenceController code.  It looks like I can just change the reference of the name of the app to make it work.  Need to muck around.  For some reason, all the tutorials base on "not" checking the Core Data option when creating the project.  So I also unchecked that when I started mine.

Comment: If you have Apple's `PersistenceController` in you app, the fix for you preview will be to add the line exactly as I wrote it in my first comment on `ListView()` in the preview provider.

Comment: @Yrb Looks like the existing code is already too ingrained. Gimme some time to redo the whole thing to incorporate Apple's PersistenceController.  Great thanks!